# DateJS: Var Passed to JS Are Not Calculating Correctly

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I am trying to do some simple calculations, I need to take a date and add x-months to that date. After searching, I decided to use DateJS to account for edge dates.

I set up a form that allows the user to enter the date and amount of months. On a keyup function, it calculates the new date. The issue is it's not calculating correctly.

I can pass the date from the form to the JS and manually specify the months in JS and it calculates correctly. If I pass both the date and months from the form the calculation is off by a lot. Years in fact!

If I replace $("#monthincrease").val() with a hard coded number the calculation works fine. But not when using data from the form.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Future Date Calculator</h1>
        <p>To calculate a future date, enter a start date and the amount of months to add.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="startdate">Start Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startdate">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="monthincrease"> And Months To Add:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="monthincrease">
              </div>
            </form>
            <p>Date: <span class="futuredate"></span></p>
            <p>Month: <span class="month"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#monthincrease").on('keyup',function() {
    var newDate = Date.parse( $("#startdate").val() ).addMonths( $("#monthincrease").val() );
    $(".futuredate").html(newDate);
    $(".month").html( $("#monthincrease").val() );
});
</script>
```

This is my updated code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Future Date Calculator</h1>
        <p>To calculate a future date, enter a start date and the amount of months to add.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="startdate">Start Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startdate">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="monthincrease"> And Months To Add:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="monthincrease">
              </div>
            </form>
            <p>Date: <span class="futuredate"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $("#monthincrease").on('keyup',function() {
        var incMonths = $("#monthincrease").val();
        var startDate = $("#startdate").val();
        var newDate = new Date.parseExact( startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd" ).addMonths( incMonths );
        $(".futuredate").html(newDate);
        console.log(incMonths);
        console.log(startDate);
        console.log(newDate);
    });
});
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: try a console.log($("#monthincrease").val()) and see if you get what you expect

Comment: I tried outputting all the var to the console and they look fine. The months return correctly based on what is entered in the input field.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe you're getting a string instead of a number in that variable. You can also try to break that chain of functions and print intermediate results

Comment: I pulled all my code into CodePen if you want to take a look. http://codepen.io/jsilva7765/pen/QbJmNa

Comment: @AnaF Thank you for your last response, it caused me to look into the var itself. I couldn't tell in the console.log output but it was storing it as a string. I change the var to var incMonths = Number( $("#monthincrease").val() ); which converted the form input into a number. Thanks, it now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in your event code in document.ready block. Also for correct calculation use parseExact method of DateJS library and specify the format in which date will be entered in textbox. https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

Updated:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
$("#monthincrease").on('keyup',function() {
        var incMonths = $("#monthincrease").val();
        var startDate = $("#startdate").val();
        var newDate = new Date.parseExact( startDate, "M/d/yyyy" ).addMonths( parseInt(incMonths ));
        $(".futuredate").html(newDate);
        });
```

});

I corrected the date format and used parseInt for months field. Try it now.

Comment: I updated my code, added in the parseExact and specified the date format. I also wrapped the function in a document.ready and still no dice. The results are the same if I replace incMonths in .addMonths( incMonths ) with a number the results are correct.

Comment: I pulled all my code into Codepen if you want to take a look. http://codepen.io/jsilva7765/pen/QbJmNa

Answer (score 0):

I change the var to var incMonths = Number( $("#monthincrease").val() ); which converted the form input into a number. Works now.